# Set API server with Parse SDK for Windows Phone

Tags: .net, parse-platform, windows-phone-8, migration, back4app

I am using Parse as a backend for my Windows Phone applications. Since Parse is shutting down, I am trying to migrate my apps with back4app service.

I updated Parse SDK for Windows Phone via NuGet Package Manager to Parse SDK 1.7 and I should now point my app to another server like this

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration {
ApplicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID",
WindowsKey = "YOUR_DOTNET_KEY",
Server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
```

});

but there is no such method in Parse SDK 1.7 for .NET. There is only Initialize method like this

```
  ParseClient.Initialize(appid, key);
```

How can I overcome this last step?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/master/ParseCore/Public/ParseClient.cs) code and it looks like it's there.

if you will go to **line number 35** you will see the configuration struct

```
public struct Configuration {
      /// <summary>
      /// In the event that you would like to use the Parse SDK
      /// from a completely portable project, with no platform-specific library required,
      /// to get full access to all of our features available on Parse.com
      /// (A/B testing, slow queries, etc.), you must set the values of this struct
      /// to be appropriate for your platform.
      ///
      /// Any values set here will overwrite those that are automatically configured by
      /// any platform-specific migration library your app includes.
      /// </summary>
      public struct VersionInformation {
        /// <summary>
        /// The build number of your app.
        /// </summary>
        public String BuildVersion { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The human friendly version number of your happ.
        /// </summary>
        public String DisplayVersion { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The operating system version of the platform the SDK is operating in..
        /// </summary>
        public String OSVersion { get; set; }
      }
```

and if you will go to **line number 144** you will see a static method that you can initialise the parse client SDK with the configuration struct

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Authenticates this client as belonging to your application. This must be
    /// called before your application can use the Parse library. The recommended
    /// way is to put a call to <c>ParseFramework.Initialize</c> in your
    /// Application startup.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration">The configuration to initialize Parse with.
    /// </param>
    public static void Initialize(Configuration configuration) {
      lock (mutex) {
        configuration.Server = configuration.Server ?? "https://api.parse.com/1/";
        CurrentConfiguration = configuration;

        ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ParseUser>();
        ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ParseRole>();
        ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ParseSession>();

        ParseModuleController.Instance.ParseDidInitialize();
      }
    }
```

So maybe you are using a wrong version or maybe it's some issue with your NuGet configuration..